# How to declare a custom jsp tag with required HashMap<String, String>?

Tags: java, jsp, hashmap, jsp-tags, custom-tag

In my class, I need a HashMap. How to declare this in tld?

```
    <attribute>
        <name>map</name>
        <required>true</required>
        <rtexprvalue>true</rtexprvalue>
        <type>java.util.HashMap</type>        
    </attribute>
```

**Update:**
The above code works. But I want to specify the type of HashMap

How is:

```
HashMap<?,?>
```

How I want:

```
HashMap<String, String>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution:

```
 <type><![CDATA[java.util.HashMap<java.lang.String, java.lang.String>]]</type>
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can specify the type there on a tag. You can do that with a custom el function:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<taglib xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee web-jsptaglibrary_2_0.xsd"
    version="2.0">
    <tlib-version>1.0</tlib-version>
    <short-name>shortname</short-name>
    <uri>http://some/uri</uri>
    <function>
        <name>testMethod</name>
        <function-class>
            somePackage.TestFunction
        </function-class>
        <function-signature>
            java.lang.String testMethod( java.util.HashMap)
        </function-signature>
    </function>
</taglib>
```

Corresponing class:

```
public class TestFunction {

public static String testMethod(HashMap<?, ?> map) {
    return map.toString();
}
}
```